# Fridge temperature

Tags: temperature, refrigerator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the ideal fridge temperature](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12013/what-is-the-ideal-fridge-temperature)

I have brought a fridge thermometer to check the temperature of a new fridge (Amica). On it's highest setting (7) it alternates over the course of about 90 mins from -2.5 degrees C to a max of 6.5 degrees C which triggers the fridge back to working as the temperature starts falling again. I just wanted to check that these temps are about right for a fridge and safe for food, milk, cream etc as I know most food talks about being under 5 degrees, and as mine goes up to 6.5, I just wanted to check this as the last fridge was problematic, hence buying the thermometer in the first place

Many thanks

Comment: I would think the fluctuations are a bigger concern than the actual temperature (if it would be steady), but I don't know. 3–5˚C is recommended by the authorities in my country. Lower than that, food might freeze. Above that, you get a short shelf life.

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4529/what-temperatures-should-i-keep-my-refrigerator-and-freezer-set-at also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12013/what-is-the-ideal-fridge-temperature/12036#12036

Comment: Did you measure those fluctuations with the fridge empty? I guess putting stuff in it will make it more stable (having more thermal mass will make it have more thermal inertia).

Comment: I'm not sure how much this effects it but are you opening the door often to check the temperature? I used to have one of those indoor/outdoor thermometers and used it to check my fridge because then I didn't have to open the door and disturb the measurement.

Comment: @lemontwist while this will give you the temp of the fridge when at rest, it's not a real "working" temp since your going to inevitably need to open your fridge and often quite frequently.